# Exclude a single commit from a "git diff"

Tags: git, git-diff

Morning all,
Let's say I have a series of commits as follows:

- abc000
- def111
- abc222
- def333
- abc444
- def555

I know I can use

```
$ git diff -c --binary abc000..def555 > /tmp/abc000_def555.patch
```

to produce a patch to upgrade a system from abc000 to def555.

But what if I wanted to (for reasons to dull to get into) *exclude* def333 from the patch - how can I do this? Note that I do not want to revert def333, its just that I do not want the patch to incorporate this commit.

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Actually *all* `git diff`s are commit-pair-wise: the above compares the trees/files in `abc000` against those in `def555`.  If for instance `def333` changes `dir/file` but there are no changes to `dir/file` between `abc000` and `def555` (e.g., the change in `def333` is canceled out by something along the way) you might not see `dir/file` in there at all.

In general, though, changes made in `def333` will have altered `dir/file` in a way that shows up when comparing the version in `abc000` against the one in `def555`.  So you will *probably* see that change.

The easiest way to get a diff that shows "what `def555` would look like if `def333` were reverted" is to do just that: create a tree (on a temporary branch) with the change reverted.  To do it with an actual named branch, you might do something like this:

```
git checkout def555 # by ID, so that you get a "detached HEAD"
git checkout -b temp-branch
git revert --no-edit def333
git diff [options] abc000
git checkout somebranch; git branch -D temp-branch
```

What if you don't want a temp branch?  Well, that's trivial: just don't create one.  Get a "detached HEAD" as above, do the revert as above, and then `git checkout somebranch`.  There's no temporary branch to delete, except for the unnamed one that git will warn that you are leaving behind ... which is just what you wanted.

Comment: You could also use `revert --no-commit`, then you wouldn't need a branch (or detached head) at all and leave nothing behind.

Comment: @Bergi: true (though you'll then need to `git reset --hard` to clean up the work-tree once you're done).

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to `git diff` and exclude one or more commits. You have to make a new branch, revert the unwanted commits, then diff it and make a patch:

```
git checkout --branch <branch-name>-diff-branch // Create a throwaway branch.
git revert <unwanted-sha> // Get rid of the unwanted commit. Do this as many times as necessary, you cannot revert multiple SHAs at once.
git diff > new.patch // Create your new patch.
git checkout - // Checkout previous branch, nice trick eh?!
git branch --delete --force <branch-name>-diff-branch // Delete the throwaway branch.
```

p.s. I didn't want to butcher torek's answer too much so I posted a new one that I think is more concise.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you create a new branch, cherry-pick the commits you need and then do the diff

Answer (score 1):

You could try using git rebase -i and then drop the commit you don't need. Another way is to cherry-pick the commits you need on a different branch.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, however I needed to do this to visually inspect the difference between two commits and I wanted to exclude some of the commits.

The most effective and easy way I found was to first use the git-format-patch command to generate all the commits in patch files on disk in a dedicated directory; and then use a command to find and delete those files that contained commit numbers which I wanted to remove. Finally, I concatenated all the remaining patch files into a single file which is what the OP is asking for.

On a Linux system with Bash you can do the following:

```
git format-patch --full-index <start-commit>..<end-commit>
mkdir all_patches
mv *.patch all_patches/
cd all_patches/
rm -rf `egrep -lsr "commit1-to-exclude|commit2-to-exclude|commit3-to-exclude" . `
cat * >> final.diff
```