# Diff only local changes in a merged branch in Git

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-diff

Using Git, I branched from "trunk" the branch "A", then committed several changes. Then, I merged from "trunk" because it was merged with branch "B" and I had to sync with those changes. Then I made additional changes on branch "A".

This is a diagram of the tree:

```
branch A:   T1--A1--A2--M--A3--*
           /           / 
   trunk: T1----------T2
           \         /
branch B:   T1--B1--B2
```

Now, I'd like to diff only local differences in branch "A", but if I diff between the commit where I branched originally and the current working tree, I also see the changes merged from branch "B".

So, in a merged branch how can I see only the changes made in that branch excluding the merges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually simple: just `git diff` working tree against the commit from which the branch has been merged. In my example this means `git diff T2`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `--author` flag to filter your changes:

```
$ git log branchpoint..HEAD --author=lorenzo
```

EDIT:

To view the contents of these changes, you could use git show:

```
$ git show branchpoint..HEAD --author=lorenzo
```

Comment: @Lorenzo I misunderstood the requirement then, sorry. `git show` should do the trick.

Comment: That's much better... but still not exactly what I'd like, because I don't see a single diff but a series of diffs, one for each commit I made. And then, if I'm the author also of the changes on the branch I merged, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977073/exclude-a-single-commit-from-a-git-diff) explanation to exclude the `merge B` commit from the diff.

Comment: Ouch, this probably works, but I hoped to find something simpler, like some magic parameter to pass to `git diff`, without the need of creating a temporary branch...